# Could not load the preview image. Please reload the page and try again - error on image upload

Tags: blog, images

i am getting this error "Could not load the preview image. Please reload the page and  try again" whenever i upload any image on my Blog Site [blog.knorish](https://blog.knorish.com/). I can see the thumbnail and image is loaded in Image folder and database with multiple sizes but on viewing it shows error, Divi Extra theme is being used to create this blog site.  I am sending you the screen shot of the error page. [image]

Comment: On the page you are having the error, use the Inspect the element on your browser and then click on console and then post here what is the error is showing on the browser console

Comment: I had the same problem... In one of my php files I had opening my opening php tags on LINE 2 and not LINE 1. Looked right over it so many times.. good luck

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case functions.php of my theme was involved.
Just remove empty space after end of `"<?php /*code or comment*/ ?> "`
There should be NO empty space between `"<?php ?>"` tags.

You can find more info: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/basic-image-editor-not-working/

Good luck!